# Connecting two laptops on same network via Ethernet cable using UDP socket

Tags: python, sockets, udp, ethernet

I have this code:

```
import io
import socket
import sys

print("Are you server or client?") 
print("\t\"s\" --- server")
print("\t\"k\" --- client")
print("To quit press \"q\"") 


def typeChoice(choice):
    if choice == 's':
        print("-----------------------------------")
        print("             Im server             ") 
        print("-----------------------------------")
        print("\n\n")

        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        bufferSize  = 1024
        msgFromServer = "\tHello client, you have been connected to server."
        bytesToSend = str.encode(msgFromServer)

        server_name = socket.gethostname() 
        server_ip = socket.gethostbyname(server_name)

        print("-----------------------------------")
        print("Ethernet IPv4 address :\t",server_ip)
        print("Set port for server :")
        server_port_string = input()
        print("-----------------------------------")
        print("\n\n")

        server_port = int(server_port_string)

        try:
            sock.bind((server_ip, server_port))
            #sock.listen()
            print("-----------------------------------")
            print('         Server has binded         ')
            print('          Im listening...          ')
            print("-----------------------------------")
        except bind_error:
            print("Bind error")
            SystemExit("Quitting program")        

        while(True):
            bytesAddressPair = sock.recvfrom(bufferSize)
            message = bytesAddressPair[0]
            address = bytesAddressPair[1]
            clientMsg = "Message from CLIENT:{}\t".format(message)
            #clientIP  = "Client IP Address:{}".format(address)            
            print(clientMsg)
            #print(clientIP)      

            sock.sendto(bytesToSend, address)

    elif choice == 'k':
        print("-----------------------------------")
        print("             Im client             ")
        print("-----------------------------------")
        print("\n\n") 

        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        bufferSize  = 1024
        msgFromClient = "\tHello server, I connected to you"
        bytesToSend = str.encode(msgFromClient)

        print("-----------------------------------")
        print("Set IP to connect to server :")
        server_ip = input()
        print("\n\n")
        print("Set port to connect to server :")
        server_port_string = input()
        print("-----------------------------------")
        print("\n\n")

        server_port = int(server_port_string)

        serverAddressConnection = (server_ip, server_port)

        try:
            sock.connect((server_ip, server_port))
            print("Connected!")
        except socket_error:
            print("NOT connected!")

        sock.sendto(bytesToSend, serverAddressConnection)

        msgFromServer = sock.recvfrom(bufferSize)
        msg = "Message from SERVER {}\t".format(msgFromServer[0])
        print(msg)
        print("Set fragment size :")
        frag_size = input()

    elif choice == 'q':
        SystemExit("Quitting program") 
    else:
        print("Wrong input!") 


choice = input()
typeChoice(choice)
```

I run this script as server first and then also as client. I run them both on one computer (I got open two command lines) and everything works as it should. On both I enter the same IP and the same port. 
Client gets message from client, that he connected to server and server gets message, that a client connected to him.

But now I connect two laptops by Ethernet cable. Both laptops are on the same network. On mine I run server, I set the port and Im waiting for client to connect. On second laptop I run client, I enter IP and port (same as server has) and then it gets "stuck". Client does not recieve a message and also server does not receive message. Just nothing happens.

I got Python v 3.7

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: server could use `0.0.0.0` to listen for clients on all network cards installed in computer.

Comment: maybe first use other tools to check if computers have connection. You can try standard `ping IP` or external [nmap](https://nmap.org/) to check what computers are visible in network.

Comment: did you connect computers directly or using switcher ? Direct connection would need "crossed cable" and will not work with normal cable which you can use with switcher. Wikipedia [Ethernet crossover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable)

Comment: Note that crossover cables are only necessary if your two computers are using older networking technology -- in particular, Gigabit Ethernet ports will generally auto-detect the direct (non-switch) configuration and handle it correctly.  (source:  https://www.networkworld.com/article/2219416/do-you-need-a-crossover-cable.html )